# Can we use React Component in the getContent function of G6.menu?

Tags: reactjs, antv

As the [document](https://antv-g6.gitee.io/en/docs/api/Plugins/#configuration-6) says, the getContent function returns `HTMLDivElement / string`.

Can we use React Component in the getContent function of G6.menu?

#### Reproduction link

[image: Edit on CodeSandbox]

#### Steps to reproduce

I try to assign a React Component in the innerHTML but it does not work.
[image]

```
const contextMenu = new G6.Menu({
    getContent(evt) {
    const outDiv = document.createElement("div");
    outDiv.style.width = "180px";
    outDiv.innerHTML = `<Menu />`;
    return outDiv;
  },
  handleMenuClick: (target, item) => {
    console.log(target, item);
  },
  // offsetX and offsetY include the padding of the parent container
  offsetX: 16 + 10,
  offsetY: 0,
  itemTypes: ["node", "edge", "canvas"]
});
```

| Environment | Info |
| --- | --- |
| g6 | 4.3.4 |
| System | macOS 10.15.6 |
| Browser | Chrome 91.0.4472.77 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const contextMenu = new G6.Menu({
    getContent(evt) {
    const outDiv = document.createElement("div");
    ReactDOM.render(<Menu />, outDiv)
    return outDiv;
  },
  handleMenuClick: (target, item) => {
    console.log(target, item);
  },
  // offsetX and offsetY include the padding of the parent container
  offsetX: 16 + 10,
  offsetY: 0,
  itemTypes: ["node", "edge", "canvas"]
});
```